# libcURL get request

Tags: http, libcurl

pretty useless at code but I can but try.
I'm trying to send a HTTP request [GET] via localhost to a radio sever program. [Windows C++]

I can send this from my browser or cmd and the result is volume is set to zero
`http://127.0.0.1:8282/parameter/hd1/spk/volume?set=0`

I can connect with my c++ app, tried both winsock & libcURL. But the volume does not change

this is pretty much the example from cURL, I'm trying the smallest incremental steps I can.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>

int main(void)
{
    CURL* curl;
    CURLcode res;

    /* In windows, this will init the winsock stuff */
    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);

    /* get a curl handle */
    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl) {

        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "127.0.0.1:8282");

        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, "/parameter/hd1/spk/volume?=0");

        /* Perform the request, res will get the return code */
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        /* Check for errors */
        if (res != CURLE_OK)
            fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
                curl_easy_strerror(res));

        /* always cleanup */
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }
    curl_global_cleanup();
    return 0;
}
```

*EDIT*
This is ridiculous, but this did it, removed the CURLOPT_HTTPGET bit, and put the full path in CURLOPT_URL,

it's not supposed to work like that is it?

`curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "127.0.0.1:8282/parameter/hd1/spk/volume?=0");`

Comment: Read the manual. [CURLOPT_HTTPGET](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_HTTPGET.html) is not a GET path, this is 0L or 1L. Use `curl --lbcurl http://127.0.0.1:8282/parameter/hd1/spk/volume?set=0` for getting working code.